# Closing Parent div and ul on click that shares another on click container but keeps unwanted li Open

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I added a span that overlays the container it's supposed to close. It does this fine, but if I click this closing span, it opens the li and closes the parent span and ul but keeps the li open (tried adding li to the .fadeout didn't work). Attaching my fiddle didn't come out how I expected so i will attach my code here:

```js
     var main = function () {
    var recipeArray = ['drink', 'firstCourse', 'mainDish', 'dessert'];
    var recipeArrayLength = recipeArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < recipeArrayLength; i++) {

        var $checkBoxes = document.createElement('div');
        $checkBoxes.setAttribute("class", "checkBoxes");
        var $recipePicContainer = document.createElement('span');
        $recipePicContainer.setAttribute("class", "recipePicContainer");



        function makeRecipePic() {

            var recipe = document.createElement("IMG");
            recipe.setAttribute("src", "../images/grasshopper-cocktail.jpg");
            recipe.setAttribute("class", "recipe");
            $recipePicContainer.appendChild(recipe);
        }
        var $deleteRecipe = document.createElement('span');
        $deleteRecipe.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-times-circle", "aria-hidden", "true");
        $recipePicContainer.appendChild($deleteRecipe);

        $($deleteRecipe).click(function(){
            $(this).parents('span', 'ul').fadeOut();
        });

        makeRecipePic();

        var mainContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('mainContainer');
        mainContainer[0].appendChild($checkBoxes);

        var $div = document.createElement('div');
        $div.innerHTML = 'CockTails';
        $recipePicContainer.appendChild($div);
        $checkBoxes.appendChild($recipePicContainer);

        var $recipes = document.createElement("ul");
        var $checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkBoxes');

        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");

        for (var j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.className = "ingredients";
            li.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");


            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.innerHTML = "Ingredient " + j;

            li.appendChild(a);
            $recipes.appendChild(li);
        }
        var b = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        li.className = "Instructions";

        $checkboxes[i].appendChild($recipes);
    }
    $('.recipes').hide();
    $('<input type="checkbox" value="1" />').prependTo(".ingredients");
    $('.mainContainer .recipePicContainer').click(function () {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle("slow").toggleClass('selected');

    });

    };
    $(document).ready(main);
```

```css
    .fa-times-circle:before {
        content: "\f057";
        position: relative;
        left: 28px;
        bottom: 125px;
        color: white;
        -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    
    <div class="mainContainer col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    
    </div>
```

Comment: Always attach code here and don't attach Fiddles. Just make sure to insert code snippets here.

Comment: Why do you use `document.createElement` and jQuery at the same time?

Comment: @PeterMader Why not? is it considered wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're forcing the user to download the entire jQuery library, but only use it to bind some event listeners. If you already use jQuery, then use it in all of your code to make it more succinct. jQuery also provides some abstractions over the native DOM API.

Comment: Thanx, i was planning on using it more later on, and to change the code eventually to jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got this bug down by just selecting all .siblings and .andSelf.
I'm sure there are other ways to do this, but this works.

JS

```
var main = function () {
    var recipeArray = ['drink', 'firstCourse', 'mainDish', 'dessert'];
    var recipeArrayLength = recipeArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < recipeArrayLength; i++) {

        var $checkBoxes = document.createElement('div');
        $checkBoxes.setAttribute("class", "checkBoxes");
        var $recipePicContainer = document.createElement('span');
        $recipePicContainer.setAttribute("class", "recipePicContainer");



        function makeRecipePic() {

            var recipe = document.createElement("IMG");
            recipe.setAttribute("src", "../images/grasshopper-cocktail.jpg");
            recipe.setAttribute("class", "recipe");
            $recipePicContainer.appendChild(recipe);
        }
        var $deleteRecipe = document.createElement('span');
        $deleteRecipe.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-times-circle", "aria-hidden", "true");
        $checkBoxes.appendChild($deleteRecipe);


            $($deleteRecipe).click(function () {
                $(this).siblings().andSelf().fadeOut();
            });

        makeRecipePic();

        var mainContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('mainContainer');
        mainContainer[0].appendChild($checkBoxes);

        var $div = document.createElement('div');
        $div.innerHTML = 'CockTails';
        $recipePicContainer.appendChild($div);
        $checkBoxes.appendChild($recipePicContainer);

        var $recipes = document.createElement("ul");
        var $checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkBoxes');

        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");

        for (var j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.className = "ingredients";
            li.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");


            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.innerHTML = "Ingredient " + j;

            li.appendChild(a);
            $recipes.appendChild(li);
        }
        var b = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
        li.className = "Instructions";

        $checkboxes[i].appendChild($recipes);
    }
    $('.recipes').hide();
    $('<input type="checkbox" value="1" />').prependTo(".ingredients");
    $('.mainContainer .recipePicContainer').click(function () {
        $(this).next('ul').toggle("slow").toggleClass('selected');

    });

};
$(document).ready(main);
```